# JPA : Entity extend with entity

Tags: jpa, java-persistence-api

How can I extend an entity with another entity but both of them referring to the same table ? Is it possible ? The structure is something like this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@NamedQuery(name="User.findAll", query="SELECT u FROM User u")
public class User implements Serializable{
    private int id;
    private String name;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@NamedQuery(name="SubUser.findAll", query="SELECT su FROM SubUser su")
public class SubUser extends User {

    @Override
    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int getId() {
      return super.getId();
    }

    //- Other fields and getter setter

}
```

I tried this way [Extend JPA entity to add attributes and logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570251/extend-jpa-entity-to-add-attributes-and-logic)

but I got this exception

```
org.hibernate.mapping.SingleTableSubclass cannot be cast to org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass
```

**Update 1**

I already put the `@Id` for the SubUser because the `@Entity` shows this exception

`The entity has no primary key attribute defined`

Comment: The Id must be specified in the base Entity, and it isn't in your example. The only time you can omit the Id from the base class would be when it is a MappedSuperclass. Inheritance defines the table used for a class in an inheritance relation, not just specifying the Table!

Answer (score 2):

- Add the @Inheritance annotation to the super class
- Implement Serializable
- Add a getter for `id` (you don't need a setter necessarily)
- `id` should be Integer, not int, so that you can represent unassigned ids with null.

Code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    public Integer getId() {
      return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
      return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }
}


@Entity
public class SubUser extends User {

}
```

Comment: I still got this error `org.hibernate.mapping.SingleTableSubclass cannot be cast to org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass`

Answer (score -1):

Any basic JPA docs would describe inheritance, discriminators and use of `@Id`.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="DISCRIM", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorValue("User")
@Table(name="users")
@NamedQuery(name="User.findAll", query="SELECT u FROM User u")
public class User implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String name;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("SubUser")
@NamedQuery(name="SubUser.findAll", query="SELECT su FROM SubUser su")
public class SubUser extends User {

}
```

Comment: If you think that the existing documentation is enough, just add a comment to the post. If you think that it is necessary to add an answer, you should better document what you are suggesting.