# JPARepository CPRQ modified does not save full object

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have modified the design of CPRQ a bit to help my database pattern

I have an Employee table and a Department table. Both have common properties

```
@Column(name="tenantIDPKFK")
private Integer tenantIdpkfk;

@Column(name="status")
private Integer status;
```

So I created a base class ABaseEntity like below

```
public class ABaseEntity {

  public ABaseEntity() {
  }

  public ABaseEntity(int tenantIdpkfk, int status) {
      this.tenantIdpkfk = tenantIdpkfk ;
      this.status = status ;
  }

  @Column(name="tenantIDPKFK")
  private Integer tenantIdpkfk;

  @Column(name="status")
  private Integer status;
```

I have extended EmployeeEntity with ABaseEntity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class EmployeeEntity  extends ABaseEntity{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    @NotEmpty(message = "Please provide a name")
    @NotBlank
    private String firstName;
```

My CommandHandler runs the following code

```
 EmployeeEntity savedEmployeeEntity = this.employeeRepository.saveAndFlush(employee);
 this.mediator.emit(new EmployeeCreatedEvent(savedEmployeeEntity.getId()));
```

Database saved the object, but only `id`, `firstname`. Does not save `tenant` and `status` columns.

I know I am missing something silly. Please help.

**EDIT**
Adding `@MappedSuperclass` to the ABaseEntity class fixed the issue.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class ABaseEntity {...}
```

Comment: Hey man, take a loot at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570251/extend-jpa-entity-to-add-attributes-and-logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Database saved the object, but only id, firstname. Does not save
> tenant and status columns.

By default JPA doesn't consider the parent class in the orm (object-relational mapping) of the current class.
You have to specify on the parent class `@Inheritance` with the strategy to use or use the default one.
For example :

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class ABaseEntity {...}
```

[More info here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance).